# Can the federal government of the United States influence when ballot totals are announced?

Tags: united-states, election, presidential-election, federalism

Would it be legal for the federal government of the United States to introduce a law, with words to the effect of:

*"No results of any congressional, senatorial, or presidential election may be announced until polls have closed in all participating states."*

Whilst I believe the conduct of the elections is in near complete control of the state, would this extend to announcement of the results?

The rationale behind this law would be to prevent announcing earlier results in an attempt to influence later voters - for instance apparently the first polls will close at 1800 Eastern Time in Indiana and Kentucky, at which time some voters in Alaska will apparently still have [7 additional hours to cast their ballot.](https://www.270towin.com/poll-closing-times) A similar provision applies in European Parliamentary elections, where votes are not permitted to be counted until Sunday, when the final polls close.

Comment: To clarify, you're asking about the Federal government passing a law binding the State election offices, right?

Comment: Sounds right - assuming they are the institution responsible for officially announcing / certifying results.

Comment: I could be wrong but I don't think any state is able to announce official results that fast because of mail in ballots (even under normal time) and other issues. However they won't be able to make a law preventing the media and other sources from announcing an expected winner.

Comment: @JoeW Announcing partial or interim results (which I think happens in the USA?), say without postal ballot could also have an influence.

Comment: Guam conducts a "straw poll" during the general election. "Because Guam is 15 hours ahead of the mainland, the poll is regarded as an indicator of how the rest of the country will vote." Is that important for this question? _See_, [2020 United States presidential election in Guam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_United_States_presidential_election_in_Guam)

Comment: Note that Senatorial races and Congressional races are only within the state anyway. This would only really apply to presidential races.

Comment: @Chipster - I was trying to find a phrasing (and couldn't)  which expressed that every race for the given institution on that date should be closed. Whilst of course if I am in the state of WestCoastia, I can't vote for the senator in EastCoastia, however if I hear that Party X has won there, it may encourage me to vote for Party Y in my local race, etc.

Comment: @JoeW India has a concept of "Aachar Sanhita" - i.e. "Code of Conduct" for election duration which mandates that "exit polls" cannot be published by media till voting hours are concluded. You're saying such a thing is not possible in  the US?

Comment: @whoisit Not when the constitution guarantees a free and unrestricted press as they are unable to make laws preventing the press from releasing results of polls they take.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Federal-level elections in the US are a state matter. Every state does their own election according to their own laws. But there is precedent for the federal government to regulate the states in this regards, like with the [voting rights act of 1965](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_Rights_Act_of_1965).

One possible constitutional challenge to such a law could be that prohibiting people from talking about the election results could be interpreted as a violation of freedom of speech. There is also the question if such a law is even enforceable in the Internet age. There are lots of people involved in counting and tallying the results (for good reason - the more people you have involved in the counting process, the harder it gets to falsify the results) and any of them could anonymously leak that information on the Internet or to the media.

But another thing the federal government could do is prohibit the states from starting to count the ballots until the last polling station has closed. There are several countries in the world where this is common practice to avoid this problem.

But in those countries where it is common practice, it often doesn't help much due to a different problem: **Exit polls**. Every media outlet in the country wants to be the first to report the election results. So what they do is send people to the polling stations who ask voters leaving the station how they voted. These polls often provide numbers which are very close to the official voting results, even before the first ballot box was opened. This would be very hard to prevent in a country like the United States where you have such strong protection of freedom of speech and freedom of press.

Comment: Another example is the law passed by Congress in 1845 that made the first Tuesday after the first Monday in November be the nationwide Election Day. This was driven in part by technology. The law before that was to hold federal elections in a 34 day period prior to the first Wednesday in December. The development of the telegraph gave early voting states the ability to influence results in later voting states.

Comment: "One possible constitutional challenge to such a law could be that prohibiting people from talking about the election results could be interpreted as a violation of freedom of speech." I understand it to be a restriction on the release of the information, not on discussing information that has been released. It's not a violation of free speech to restrict the government from releasing information.

Comment: "Federal-level elections in the US are a state matter. " - I love your phrasing in this sentence. A beautiful example of either the checks-and-balances of the American political system, or the contradictions inherent to it.

Comment: "There is also the question if such a law is even enforceable in the Internet age" actually I know of people who would just call their friends who are counting votes if they are anxiously waiting for results and would like an inside opinion. No internet required.

Comment: Freedom of speech may be restricted in the service of a compelling government interest under certain conditions. A well crafted law would probably survive a constitutional challenge.  But such a law is unnecessary because media voluntarily refrain from reporting exit polling until the last polls have closed.

Comment: Can you say how "Federal-level elections in the US are a state matter"? How could anything federal be a state matter? How could that not deny the Constitution of the USA?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin What I meant with that is that even though the elections are *for* the federal level, the elections are *performed by* the states. That means each states prepare, execute, counts and ratifies the results of federal-level elections within their state on their own. The federal government did pass a couple laws over the years which put some restrictions on how to conduct these elections, but there are still considerable differences between how states do federal-level elections. For example, Maine and Nebraska split their presidential votes by districts.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin If you have any further questions on elections in the United States, feel free to ask them as new questions.

Answer (score 3):

> No results of any congressional, senatorial, or presidential election may be announced until polls have closed in all participating states.

That might well be unconstitutional. The Constitution relegates control of federal-level elections to the states. What might be constitutional is a law that states that

*All federal subsidies to states pertaining to elections shall be withheld from states that release federal election results before polls have closed in all participating states.*

The federal government has used withholding funds it nominally provides to states as a way of getting around what would otherwise be consitutional limitations.

Another possibility would be the ongoing state-level effort to make the Electoral College meaningless, the National Popular Vote Interstate Compact. Those states could add a clause to the compact to withhold election results in each state until all polls in the signatory states have ended. And then invite Alaska to join to compact.

Comment: The federal government regulates federal elections in other ways without resorting to the power of the purse.  There's no reason to think that this restriction would be unconstitutional.

Answer (score 2):

Such a law would be pretty hard to square with the First Amendment.  It is highly unlikely that the courts would allow the government to limit what journalists were allowed to report.  Someone might make a case that there is a compelling public interest in preventing publication and cause some justice to create a balancing test that would allow such a law but such a decision would be unprecedented.

If you wanted to prevent results from early states from being published, you would realistically need to convince the national networks to hold off publishing the voting data they receive until after the last polls close.  They already voluntarily hold off on calling individual states until after that state's polls close (though periodically there are mistakes such as 2000 when [Florida was called before the Central time zone counties had finished voting](https://www.cnn.com/ALLPOLITICS/time/2000/11/20/close.html)).  It is conceivable that they could be convinced to hold off until all states finished voting particularly if mail-in ballots become more common and networks worry about the "blue shift" where Republican candidates are ahead based on the results of in-person ballots while additional Democratic ballots arrive after Election Day.

Comment: Journalists cannot report what they do not know. The western part of Florida is in the Central Time Zone. Polls close in most of Florida an hour before they close in western Florida. Florida requires local election officials to refrain from releasing election results until polls have closed in western Florida. The penalties for premature release are severe. Florida will start counting mail-in ballots on November 2 this year. Election officials who release that information are subject to even more severe penalties. IIRC, it is a felony.

Comment: @DavidHammen - It is a fact that in 2000, the Voter News Service called Florida for Gore prior to polls closing in the Florida panhandle.  That was based on exit polls and early voting results.  Perhaps the laws have changed in the last 20 years and early voting results can no longer be disclosed or perhaps officials released some data early on accident 20 years ago.  Regardless, it is still perfectly legal for the major networks to call a state before the polls close based solely on polling data.  It is something that they decline to do out of a sense of civic duty.

Comment: Because Florida is starting to count mail-in ballots a day before Election Day this year, Florida has made it a felony for an election official to disclose the results of the early voting before polls close statewide.

Comment: @DavidHammen I think you are confusing official results and numbers from the states and the numbers that the media gets from polling.

Comment: @JoeW I think not. I am specifically talking about official results. People have learned to to walk right past pollsters at polling places, to not answer phone calls from pollsters, and to sometimes lie to pollsters when people do deign to talk to them. Watching polls before elections and on election night is a fun sport, but it is not the real thing. We would be talking about President Thomas Dewey and President Hilary Clinton if pollsters decided elections. But they don't.

Comment: @DavidHammen Official results are not announced until all the ballots have been counted. Some places may release numbers as they count but those are never official results.

Comment: @JoeW "Official" does not necessarily mean "final". The results released by states (not by polling organizations) on a precinct-by-precinct basis regarding day of the election results are official results, by definition, as they were released by government officials.

Comment: @DavidHammen - Ah,  the sloppiness of language. It could also be reasonably argued that "official" results become official when the state certifies the election results. " Certification is the process by which the results of an election are made official."  in Florida that date is set at 14 days after election day, in this year that would be Nov 17th https://dos.myflorida.com/media/703440/final-elections-calendar-2019-2021-updated-20200821-complete.pdf

Comment: @BobE - Waiting for two weeks to see even tentative results would not be deemed acceptable in this day of expectations for near instantaneous results. The OP is asking for a delay of seven hours, not a fortnight.

Comment: @DavidHammen - now you seem to be making a distinction between tentative and official. Or maybe you mean official tentative results.  As far as reporting results, Dixville Notch, NH typically will report their precinct results before 12:15 AM on election day. You could argue that it influences the remainder of Coos County, as well as New Hampshire in general. One could go even farther and suggest that the announcement influences the voters in every state - LOL

Answer (score -4):

If you're really suggesting no political parties, media or independent observers should be allowed to publish running exit counts, please say so.

Can the feds influence when ballot totals are announced isn’t at all the same Question as whether it would be legal to introduce a law, with words to the effect of "No results of any… election may be announced until all polls have closed" or whatever else. Which are you Asking about?

If you’re suggesting ”No results of any election may be officially announced until all polls have closed" then if that’s not how it is now, who doubts it should be?

How could you or I or anyone distinguish “an attempt to influence later voters” from a simple desire to report the results so far?

Comment: By the way, why not look at Tuesday's actual results, in terms both of votes cast and of laws invoked?